# How can I simplify the summation $\sum_{n\ge1} n!x^n$ to a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was trying to simplify $$\sum_{n\ge1} n!x^n$$ so that I can remove the summation sign.
I tried to expand and look for any pattern but failed.
Can someone help with this?
Thank you!

Comment: For what values of $x$ does the series converge?

Comment: @Alann Rosas When x < 1/(n+1)?

Comment: $n$ is a dummy variable. It doesn't have a value here because it's being used as the index of summation.

Comment: if it's infinite series, it will not converge for any $x$ except $x=0$ as $n!$ grows faster than $x^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series is divergent if $x\neq 0$ as shown by a quick ratio test. Now, you can assign a meaning to it via summation methods. A natural one in this case is *Borel summation*:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n!x^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \left(\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^n \mathrm{e}^{ - t} \mathrm{d}t}\right) x^n  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(xt)^n } \mathrm{e}^{ - t} \mathrm{d}t}  = x\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t\mathrm{e}^{ - t} }}{{1 - xt}}\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
The last integral is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (0,+\infty)$ and is related to the *exponential integral* $\operatorname{Ei}$ via $
(1/x)\mathrm{e}^{ - 1/x} \operatorname{Ei}(1/x) - 1$. Your series is a divergent *asymptotic expansion* for the integral as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p n!\, x^n$$ let $x=-\frac 1 y$ and using the imcomplete gamma function
$$S_p=e^y\, y \,\Big[\Gamma (0,y)+(-1)^p \,\Gamma (p+2)\, \Gamma (-p-1,y)\Big]-1$$

Comment: How did you derive this?